# Graphic in Excel file deleted when exporting data from R when the graph has additional text

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, export, import

I have trouble when exporting data that I have created in `R` into an Excel file containing a graphic with additional text.
The problem is relatively specific as it does not happen without the additinonal text (but that I need).

So I have a datatable in R, like this one :

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
library(openxlsx)

MWE <- data.table(
  Date=rep(seq(ymd("2020-1-1"), ymd("2020-3-30"), by = "days")),
  Country1=rnorm(90,2,3),
  Country2=rnorm(90,2,3))
```

I then export it in an Excel file using an openxlsx option

```
Fichier <- loadWorkbook("File.xlsx")
writeData(Fichier, sheet="Data", MWE , colNames=T)
saveWorkbook(Fichier,"File.xlsx",overwrite=T)
```

Now this datatable, now in an Excel sheet, is used to create a graph (two curves with the values for Country 1 and Country 2 over time), in a separate sheet.

Everything works, until I add some text on the graphics (e.g. "source : Eurostat"), which then tells me that (approximate translation) : `We have encountered a problem with the file "file.xlsx" but we can try to retrieve the maximum amount of information. If this file is reliable, click on yes`. Then I get the following message and the graphic is deleted

[image]

This happens whether the graphic is in the same sheet or not

Is it specific to me or does someone can reproduce the problem ?
What can be done ?